# How do I disable pollution in Freeciv?

Tags: freeciv

Is it possible to disable pollution in Freeciv? If so, how?

The image below shows a city with lots of polluted tiles. I would like to play a game that has no pollution at all.

[image: Freeciv pollution]

I know that there is a setting for disabling global warming, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Freeciv version: 2.6.2

Comment: Relevant thread in the Freeciv forum: [How do you disable pollution?](https://forum.freeciv.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=105062)